# VueJs 2 - Using Multiple Custom Filters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Vuejs 2.0 deprecated the built in filters (filterby, orderby, limitby) when using v-for. I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the filterby and orderby filters.

I have both filters working separately, but when I try to combine them together I'm running into issues.

### Relevant template section:

```
<tr class="vu-row" v-for="item in tableFilter">
  <td v-for="head in columns">{{item[head[".key"]]}}</td>
</tr>
```

### Relevant script sections:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import db from './db'

export default {
  firebase: {
    sections: db.ref('HE'),
    columns: db.ref('Columns')
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      query: 'queryGet',
      sortkey: 'sortkeyGet',
      sortorders: 'sortOrdersGet'
    }),
    tableFilter: function () {
      return this.orderBy(function () {
        return this.findBy(this.sections, this.query, 'Designation')
      }, this.sortorders[this.sortkey], this.sortkey)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    findBy: function (list, value, column) {
      return list.filter(function (item) {
        return item[column].includes(value)
      })
    },
    orderBy: function (list, order, column) {
      return list.sort(function (a, b) {
        return order * (a[column] - b[column])
      })
    }
  },
........(more irrelevant code)
}
```

The `sections` data consists of an array of objects that I'm trying to loop through and filter.

The issue is with the `tableFilter` computed property. I don't know how to properly chain the 2 `findBy` and `orderBy` functions. Each filter works on its own when I call them individually.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

## **Edit**

For reference I created these fiddles. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greene48/c8er3kza/2/) with working search (search only searches the first column, and it is case sensitive), and [here is one](https://jsfiddle.net/greene48/o8LL87bv/1/) with working sort when clicking on table headers (although sorting by the first column isn't working for some reason).

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greene48/f8p52n04/1/) where I try to chain the 2 functions. I can't seem to get it to run.

Comment: How did you try to chain them?

Comment: Also note that "[...] filters are primarily designed for text transformation purposes. For more complex data transforms in other directives, you should use Computed properties instead." ([Source](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters))

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - I am using a computed property. The `tableFilter` computed property in my above code is where I try to chain my 2 methods (findBy and orderBy)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for explanations and illustration. However, considering such functions have been deprecated, did you find what the devs now consider as the way to do such functions, using `v-for` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.
The mass miss typo and some other small stuff.
Sorting numbers, of course not sorting strings.

`check code in JSFiddle`
https://jsfiddle.net/62u2e4bj/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, to be clear, I am using a computed property. The `tableFilter` computed property in my above code is where I try to chain my 2 functions (findBy and orderBy). I guess my problem is I don't know how to properly combine the 2 functions.

Comment: Ah, yes. Can you create JSBin/Fiddle for that? I will then try to help

Comment: Ok, this took longer than it should have because my actual app uses single file components. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greene48/c8er3kza/2/) with working search, and [here is one](https://jsfiddle.net/greene48/o8LL87bv/1/) with working sort when clicking on table headers. So I'm looking chain these two functions someonw. Obviously, the way I tried in my original post doesn't work.

Comment: Let's start from the begining. First of all - you have misstype in sortOrders. Keep camelCase always. That's first to fix.

Comment: You got it, thanks. I swear I tried that solution at some point, but I must have done something wrong. Also, in case anyone else is wondering why sorting the first column doesn't work, I just needed to replace this line in the orderBy function: `return order * (a[column] - b[column])` with this: `return order * (a[column] < b[column])`